# can not save multiple datarow in datable

Tags: c#

I want to save multiple rows in a datatable but it does not work. The output error (ArgumentException) is:
row already belongs to another table.

My Code:

When I click on 'Ok' in the second form it gonna execute the following code:

```
private void writerow()
{
    DataRow r = settings.NewRow();
    r["Folder"] = folderTextBox.Text;
    r["Filter"] = filterTextBox.Text;
    r["Subject"] = subjectTextBox.Text;
    r["Body"] = bodyTextBox.Text;
    FolderWatch.setfolderasdatarow(r); // save in a static List<DataRow>
    Foldersetting = settings;
}
private DataTable Foldersetting
{
    get { return datatblfoldersetting; }
    set { datatblfoldersetting = value; }
}
```

A click on the save icon in the first form will do this:

```
        foreach (DataRow d in FolderWatch.getfolderasdatarow())
        {
            Foldersetting.Rows.Add(d);
        }
        Foldersetting.WriteXml(ConfigurationPath + "config.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a `DataRow` to a `DataTable` that is already part of another `DataTable`.

Use this overload of [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create a new `DataRow` instead:

```
foreach (DataRow d in FolderWatch.getfolderasdatarow())
{
    Foldersetting.Rows.Add(d.ItemArray);
}
```

Comment: Or you can use [`ImportRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, `ImportRow` is also an option, but you have to keep in mind that `ImportRow` preserves the `DataRowState` of the `DataRow` that should be added. Probably not a problem in this case, though.

Answer (score 0):

Exception message is clear; "row already belongs to another table."
you can not add row which is a member of another dataTable.

d can not add  Foldersetting.Rows.

you should use

```
var fr = Foldersetting.NewRow();
```

and map d columns to added fr row. the simpliest  sample.

```
fr["column1"] = d["column1"];
fr["column2"] = d["column2"];
```